# Has anyone on EL&U been awarded the 'I See Your Point' hat yet?

Tags: discussion, unicorns, winterbash-2013

The unicorn hat is still stumping those of us who discuss these things in chat. Has anyone had it awarded yet? And is anyone ready to break the oath of silence that comes with it?

Alternatively, is anyone interested in discussing it and/or making jokes or other jovial observations?

Our chains are getting overgrown, so make sure to focus your efforts on the answers that don't have as many comments. Kthxbai.

Comment: Make some comments on Meta and we will help you.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: @Jim Some comments? I don't see how that will help anything. *sulks*

Comment: @Hugo Do you?  Do you really?

Comment: No. Not really.

Comment: I saw my point yesterday. Your point was nowhere to be seen.

Comment: I can’t see the point.  Do you have to Believe for this to work?  Perhaps it’s tied to virginity.

Comment: @Hugo And I see yours.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm still looking for your point.

Comment: Can people help me get my point across please?

Comment: I'll show you my point if you show me yours.

Comment: I don't see the point of a unico.. Oh, now I get it.

Comment: No, I don't get it at all.

Comment: Too many points! They sticks in my eyes. HELP I'M BLEEDING.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ Most of those are good points to make.

Comment: But they're sharp.

Comment: Have an o, I'd rather have a pint.

Comment: By the way, what coat color is pinto?

Comment: Wait... Unicorn avatar in unicorn hat... Would that make me a bicorn?

Comment: These comments are getting increasingly corny.

Comment: Reading all this you feel like you're lost in a maize.

Comment: I feel like I am reading PI in the comments list.

Comment: Alternatively, what does the KitFox say?! See what I did there? =D

Comment: @CodeMaverick No, I don't :-(

Comment: @snailboat - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE You will now =D

Comment: Aaah! Daily vote limit reached! That's what I get for trying to upvote every single comment in this thread!

Comment: I feel your pain, @CodeMaverick. But it's a whole new day now! (Hint, hint)

Comment: @Martha - Right you are +1's for everyone!!!!!!!! =D

Comment: I think I've figured it out based on the unnaturally high number of comment upvotes here. Do I win a prize?

Comment: This is a +1 free-for-all!!!!

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers It's for the greater good.

Comment: I'm late on this.

Comment: I usually refuse to acknowledge anyone else's point unless it agrees with mine, but I don't have one. yet.

Comment: Sometimes I rehash old points over and over until they get pointer or worn down to a nub.

Comment: I've heard that my point is hiding here somewhere, but so far it doesn't even come out for special unicorn treats!  Those marketing people totally lied about those being addicting.

Comment: Eesh, is there a comment limit?

Comment: @MrHen: I wonder if I can flag myself...

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I see your point? Maybe?

Comment: @MrHen indeed you do. :-)

Comment: Now I see your point!

Comment: And now the system suggest us to go to chat room. NOOOOOOO. I will stay here!

Comment: Points and points and points.

Comment: I would like to make a point, but I think it was already made.

Comment: Hang on, one of my points is missing...

Comment: It rolled under the table.

Comment: Now down the hall.

Comment: Anybody see my point? I don't see my OWN point yet.

Comment: My favorite expression . . . "Good Point!  (It's nothing a hat won't cover)" lol!

Comment: Any comment?  Does it have to include "I see your point!" or "I believe in Unicorns"?  I believe!  I believe!

Comment: @KristinaLopez "any comment"? *"Any comment"?* I for one am seeing comments all over the place! What I'm still not seeing is the point... You, meanwhile, will see a unicorn shortly. So watch out, he's pointy.

Comment: I hope so  @RegDwigнt, it's the only hat I've really coveted. Lol!

Comment: Whoa! This is one very comment-rich post!

Comment: It's a pity that there are only a few unicorns in the wild nowadays.

Comment: I think only five of them left.

Comment: Possibly one unicorn per each continent.

Comment: Am I talking to myself?

Comment: Yes I am. It is always nice to talk to a people that at least as smart as you.

Comment: @Artemix Can I @ myself?

Comment: Oh, I see my point!

Comment: This is a very pointed discussion.

Comment: @Hellion It is strange though that I was not invited in the chat with me. Possible bug?

Comment: Why does this post have so many comments? Do you get a hat when your comments are upvoted on meta?

Comment: I'm disappointingly late to the party!

Comment: I don't believe in hats either.

Comment: @David you are exactly one comment short of learning the answer... Or rather, seeing the point. And two ears.

Comment: Can I shamelessly request that people please upvote my answer so I can get the Horror hat?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If this answer gets to 40 upvotes, I will get my "Oh the Horror" hat.

Please help, especially if you're one of those to have received the hat from me on the club question.

Comment: Another comment.

Comment: That was blunt.

Comment: @Ste: I've flagged you comment as offensive. It's offensively _awesome_!

Comment: Which unicorn? :)

Comment: Witch unicorn!!

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: You can now see my point!

Comment: @SF. Witch unikowrn?

Comment: Did you get email from the unicorn too?

Comment: Email from the unicorn? I want some!

Comment: Did it work? I hope so.

Comment: where have all the unicorns gone, long time passing....

Comment: I wish I may, I wish I might, to get a unicorn hat tonight!

Comment: Mary had a unicorn, unicorn, unicorn.  Mary had a unicorn that she wore as a hat!

Comment: Jeremiah was a unicorn, was a good hat of mine, I never understood a single horn he said, but I always poked with mine!

Comment: Unicorns really do exist, except they're fat and brown. [See?](http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/004/cache/black-rhino_468_600x450.jpg?01AD=35DK_Gk8TGijrX30vXltQ_XZh8-5406ZbYP8zetSdYEnSUAHszvqx2g&01RI=AE91D2BE4CB5649&01NA=)

Comment: Hats off to you!

Comment: unicorn comment?

Answer (score 17):

This place sure puts the "HAT" in "WHAT THE HECK IS GOING ON?"

Comment: Hint: an answer is not the answer to the hat you seek.

Comment: Who bit you, J.R.?

Comment: @cornbread - A shark? It wasn't a dog...

Comment: Is that a bite, or a single puncture wound such as a single-horned creature might make?

Comment: @NiallC. - I can't tell what this bloody wound is, but I have the distinct impression I'm supposed to upvote your comment for some reason.

Comment: I wonder if "No Comments" counts as a comment.

Comment: @J.R. I see that magical hat has eluded you? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: I've clicked answers, questions, shoes and fingers too. I've posted comments, and I've wished, wished, wished till my ears have popped. But still no unicorn in sight. Has it all been a pointless exercise? *sigh* What thinks you? Click if you agree...

Comment: Maybe now, you see the point? You should visit FF's post. I was confused but now it is unequivocally clear.

Comment: I think you've missed two or three points. Please, reply ASAP!

Answer (score 13):

I have been awarded that hat.

One person at [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211979/i-dont-see-your-point-how-do-i-earn-this-unicorn-hat) suggested it might be tied to accepted answers in meta. Of course that might be specific to meta.se, rather than j random meta.

There are also suggestions that it's tied to comment activity in meta, either comment upvotes or comment replies.

Comment: That's not it...?

Comment: @KitFox It might have something to do with the name: “I see your point”.

Comment: @Gilles Well, I thought so, but...I guess I'm thick. I don't get it.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: @KitFox [The secret is out.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211979/i-dont-see-your-point-how-do-i-earn-this-unicorn-hat/212277#212277)

Comment: No, no, I still don't get it.

Comment: I get it! Oh, wait, I forgot that I don't.

Comment: What, here too?

Comment: @tchrist Apparently so.

Comment: @KitFox Did you get it yet?

Comment: @MετάEd Get what?

Comment: @KitFox- You should have it now. Right?

Comment: I want a unicorn hat!

Comment: I guess I have to comment a lot more than that, though, don't I?

Comment: I need to comment a lot too.

Comment: And one hat more for luck!

Comment: Unicorns are pointy.

Comment: Can things be mispelled to count?

Comment: All I want for Christmas is a _unicorn hat_, a _unicorn hat_, a _unicorn hat_!

Comment: @CodeMaverick Would that be a *tricorn*, then?

Comment: @snailboat - It was actually my attempt at a parody =D

Comment: I'm not seeing the point. Which is sad. Can y'all help me see the point?

Comment: @CodeMaverick If I could only whistle!

Comment: [You know how to whistle, don't you, Ste^H^H^H@WendiKidd? You just put your lips together and... blow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Have_and_Have_Not_(film))

Comment: I don't *think* MSO (nee MSE) has its own hat rules, but you never know -- unicorns can work their magic in unexpected ways!

Comment: You made me believe in unicorns!

Comment: Points and unicorns for everyone!

Comment: I can feel the point!

Comment: Not getting the unicorn - I really want the unicorn. :-(

Comment: I'd love one too!

Comment: I don't really see the point.

Comment: I shall name my unicorn Pointy McPointerson and we will ride together to the gumdrop forest.

Answer (score 12):

It is my true and firm belief that you must believe in unicorns to get this hat. I don't, and as you can clearly see, I have no hat.

Comment: I believe in unicorns. *And* I also believe in points. Where is my two hats?

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think it’s the virginity thing.

Comment: Wait, is this one of the Puppetry of the Sockies thing?

Comment: No, socketry of the puppies.

Comment: @Hugo Vixen have puppies? Or are they kits?

Comment: Hat das Einhorn Erdnüsse essen zum Frühstück?

Comment: Credo in unum Unicornem, equum omnipotentem.

Comment: Well that's lucky for no hat.

Comment: I don't have this hat yet and I am upset about the fact.

Comment: I have never seen a conversation with so many upvotes. Even the ones that aren't in English. Something very strange is going on, and I want in on it. I think. :^)

Comment: Can I get the hat anyway, because I believe that other people believe in unicorns?

Comment: My points are broken.

Comment: That's not consistent. Unless it is.

Comment: @MattЭллен I don't believe that is true.

Comment: Oh no! What can I do to restore your faith?

Comment: @aediaλ I back my faith up regularly, just in case.

Comment: @snailboat - Do you back it up on a flash drive or do you have a failover RAID setup?

Comment: @J.R. yes, please get in on it. [The more the merrier](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard), after all.

Comment: But the kitty on your gravatar has a santa hat!

Comment: Gravatar hats can be pointy or soft

Comment: Is the unicorn hat invisible and pink?

Comment: If you can't see it, it doesn't exist; like spam before you open the can.

Comment: Does gaming hats actually work?  Let's find out if the unicorns are receptive!

Comment: Believer here, when will unicorn come to me?

Comment: @hwlau I hope so.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Don't worry, we will be there

Comment: Is there an extra point for me?

Comment: @AmericanLuke Yup

Comment: Pointy hats are awesome... anytime now...

Comment: Oh pointy birds, so pointy pointy.

Comment: And no matter what they tell you, size of had DOES matter!

Answer (score 12):

> [Everytime a child says 'I don't believe in fairies' there is a little fairy somewhere that falls down dead.](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/37512.html)

...so by implication...

> If you *do* believe in unicorns, they *don't* die (they continue to ***exist***).

Thus the power of thought/belief sustains fairies, unicorns, the hypothetical multiverse we (seem to) inhabit, and my hopes for getting one of these legendary hats. Unless I'm too late.

Comment: I believe in fairies, unicorns, reality, and the idea that to get one of these hats it's necessary for all comments on my answer to be upvoted. I promise to upvote any comments that agree with this perspective. And any that don't. *And* any that are "non-commital".

Comment: I neither agree nor disagree, but do see your point.

Comment: I’m so confused.  What is this?

Comment: @PLL. If you keep commenting (and upvoting other comments), a most magical hat shall be thine.

Comment: I should also say that five times two equals ten (if you see my point).

Comment: Needz moar comments.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Since it's the season of goodwill as well as monoceran headgear, I would like to make one final [point...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212277/174568)

Comment: @ekhumoro: You'll have to bear in mind that I can be *very* slow on the uptake, but I can't help noticing that you're [somewhat pointedly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22somewhat+pointedly%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) repeating a certain word. Does that imply I can get one of these hattie thingies just for mentioning that I really like [Harry Nillson's "The Point"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGFlACG6qvI)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Unlikely, but you never know... As it stands, we're currently short of another participant who can turn one point into two (five times over).

Comment: [Nobody likes me 
Everybody hates me 
Just because I eat worms  
*and covet hats*](http://www.theboys.co.uk/lwormsong.htm)

Comment: I have some of [this](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e5a7/) if anyone is interested.

Comment: @Jim. You make an excellent point. Thanks.

Comment: It's never too late to believe! Is it true if I add a comment, close my eyes, click my red shoes together, and wish really hard, I too will receive a unicorn hat?

Comment: @Mari-LouA. Such a hat requires wishing five times harder.

Comment: Five times @ekhumoro, then what's the point in upvoting comments? Please, point me in the right direction!

Comment: @Mari-LouA. [I couldn't possibly comment on that :)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212277/174568)

Comment: @ekhumoro I see... but you have helped me, I think, I hope, to get a little closer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I had hoped that the clue in my comment would get you as close as you need to get - but I'm not sure that it really _clicked_ for you...

Comment: @ekhumoro Perhaps I over-indulged myself at Xmas, I feel stuffed like a turkey and I'm still digesting what you've told me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. I'm starting to wonder whether I'm the victim of an elaborate troll in this thread :P But I'm determined not to put a direct spoiler in any of my comments. So I will simply say that the link I posted (twice) _does_ contain an indirect spoiler that can be sniffed out by a mouse.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I need a little help. A little direction pointing me the right way. I feel I am close. I have even asked J.R to lend a hand but he hasn't seen ekhumoro's point.

Comment: *Beams* I do like hats! :)

Answer (score 10):

This is my first post on Meta.ELU in a long time, and I've just earned the hat.

This confirms the hypothesis that

> this is not about upvotes on posts, but on comments. Experimentally, the comments can be all in one thread,

Comment: The same thread, you say?

Comment: I've heard that different threads are allowed.

Comment: It's funnier if you get stabbed to death by unicorns in the same thread.

Comment: What's this I hear about people not believing in unicorns?!? *looks around sharply*

Comment: @aedia you will have to repeat that point three more times for it to count. And then one more time for me to get it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - So 1 + 3 + 1 = 5?

Comment: @CodeMaverick: well, 2 + 2 = 5 for sufficiently large values of 2, so...

Comment: @CodeMaverick But 1 + 1 = Window.

Comment: Unicorns and pointy hats are awesome

Comment: One more pointy comment for good measure. Points and Unicorns!

Comment: @AmericanLuke It gets old after a while. I shall henceforth only upvote comments that I enjoy sufficiently. Try haikus, or puns, or other witticisms. (*Good* ones only.)

Comment: Points and hats are cool/
So lets all get pointy hats/
And wear them with style

Comment: Haiku isn't my thing. :S But, my point is I want a unicorn hat :P http://instantrimshot.com/

Comment: Limericks are fine too. Note that haikus should preferably reference nature or seasons, and limericks should preferably be suggestive if not baudy.

Comment: There was a young man from Missouri / who asked a fellow from Paris / to help him get a hat / so at his desk he sat / But lacking scansion he was sorry.

Comment: Ok. There's no way I can get any better than that, so no *point* in trying :P

Comment: @Gilles A "baudy" limerick is presumably one whose scansion can be measured in bits per second.

Comment: Now I do see your point!

Comment: @Gilles: very good limerick by the way.

Answer (score 8):

I think I read somewhere it's do with rollbacks.

Is that true?

Let's find out!

Comment: That didn't work. Maybe it needs a comment from someone else, then a rollback.

Comment: Maybe it won't work if you roll back your own edit. Wouldn't that be too easy?

Comment: OK. I'll roll back and see what happens...

Comment: I don't think so: I got it on SO, and [I haven't rolled anything back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/149076/gilles?tab=activity&sort=all). It's been [suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211979/i-dont-see-your-point-how-do-i-earn-this-unicorn-hat) that this has something to do with comment replies.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: An official hint: [“Earned ten of the most meaningless points on the 'Net”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211749/winter-bash-2013-secret-hats/211750#211750)

Comment: I see my point.

Comment: How do you define meaning?

Comment: I think it's unrelated to rollbacks.

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with roll backs

Comment: Too pointy, I think.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ No such thing!

Comment: I don't see your point or my point? What _is_ the ^ of all this?

Comment: @CodeMaverick I don't know, but I'll lend you a point if you lend me one of yours! :-)

Comment: @snailboat - Seems reasonable =D

Comment: @CodeMaverick You got my last point!  (This is the first time I've ever run out of comment votes, I think.)

Comment: @snailboat, there ought to be a hat for running out of comment votes.

Comment: @Marthaª I think that's a brilliant idea for a hat!

Comment: There's a limit to comment votes?  Uh-oh...

Comment: @CodeMaverick A limit on comment votes? Unfair.

Answer (score 8):

My theory is that it has to do with getting the Coding Horror hat and some other highfalutin' hat like Bounty Hunter.  [This guy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211979/i-dont-see-your-point-how-do-i-earn-this-unicorn-hat) from Gilles' comment has both of those.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: No, I have the “I see your point” but not Bounty Hunter. Michael Hampton had it before he had Coding Horror.

Comment: Seems like the unicorn horn would part that hair nicely.

Comment: I think a point still remains to be seen.

Comment: This still isn’t pointy.

Comment: It's a good theory.

Comment: I would like to have a point.

Comment: If it impales you, is it still a point?

Comment: Why did I answer this hat?

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 I see your point

Comment: What if soy milk is just regular milk introducing itself in Spanish?

Comment: For the record, I totally believe in unicorns.  And magic.  In a young girl's heart.  I mean hat.

Comment: Yay! But I haven't got a record player...

Comment: All these people, still not getting the point. Sad.

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 Then I'm afraid of my talking milk?

Comment: Why am I still awake?

Comment: Why am I still commenting?

Comment: It's a strange compulsion, @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇

Comment: It's all about points and pointy hats

Comment: I don't have anything new to add after all.

Comment: Well some are  quicker than others.

Answer (score 8):

I think you can figure out the unicorn hat by looking at all the comments on this question, regardless of whether you read them.

Comment: I didn't read your answer so I didn't understand the ... point of it.

Comment: What is the point, after all?  Earn the hat, give it up on January 4th?

Comment: Reading comments is a good thing - everyone's point of view is important

Comment: You've really made the point.

Comment: @Kristina: I'm not convinced "everyone's point of view is important". In fact, I'm going to make a point of *not* reading this comment (which I'm writing whilst looking away!), on the grounds that I strongly suspect closer examination would simply expose it as being totally pointless.

Comment: And I'm responding to your pointless comment by looking away as I type as well.  And your  "point" was good so I upvoted it. Happy Christmas and New Year FF! :-)

Comment: If I post a comment at different points of the thread, will I get that *horny* hat?

Comment: Ahh, maybe I if ask my question pointedly? @KristinaLopez what says you?

Comment: Persistance, enough comments with a coupla upvotes and you'll get the point(y hat). :-). Keep going and I'll help!

Answer (score 5):

I think you can only get the Unicorn hat by getting something posted to boingboing which is so horrible/horrifying that it *requires* a "unicorn chaser."

Comment: Why? Is boingboing so awful? I used to read it waaay back in 2003-6

Comment: @Mari-LouA  No-- for a while the mods at boingboing used to follow any story containing bad news (terrorism, government revolutions, Justin Bieber) with a picture of one unicorn or another as a "mind cleanser" :-)

Comment: I see! You learn something new everyday.